# How long does doughnut dough need to chill? What is meant by "chill over night?"

Tags: chilling

In the recipe it says chill over night, but how many hours would that mean?

Comment: Welcome to the site @Chloe, unfortunately your question cannot be answered as is because there's no context. If you could post the recipe and method you'll get better answers.

Comment: In general, terms like overnight are fudge numbers with no exact meaning and indicate the recipe has some level of flexibility, similar to terms like a pinch of salt.  Overnight is, roughly, put it in the fridge, go to bed, get up in the morning and it should be good to go.  Figure 6-10 hours.  But, as GdD states, more details, including the recipe might earn you a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 4):

"Overnight" is just a word, not a precise cooking term, so it would mean "during the time that typical people have retired for the night". I.e. 5 or 6 hours should do it. In cases where it is possible to *over*-do it (like yeast dough rising), I think the upper limit would be 10 or 12 hours.

"Overnight" is a pretty lax instruction. If the recipe requires something more precise than what laymen would assume from the word, then the time would have been specified in hours.

Comment: I've always assumed that most people aren't baking up until they go to sleep, then immediately when they get up.  (I only do that once a year).  So I've always assumed it's 12 to 24 hours.  Really, it's either to let it chill all the way through, or wait for something to change (yeast to grow, gluten to develop, moisture to even out, enzymes to work, etc.)